# Граф с помощью односвязных циклических списков

Tags: c++

Задание: реализовать граф с помощью односвязных циклических списков (включение и исключение узла).

Знаю, как реализовать циклический список и как он работает, но не могу понять, как использовать его в графах.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов задания графа - [списки смежности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Их вполне можно реализовать с использованием односвязных списков

> Кормен и другие предложили реализацию, в которой вершины представлены
> числовым индексом в массиве, в котором каждая ячейка массива ссылается
> на однонаправленный связанный список соседних вершин

Собственно, и массив вершин можно заменить односвязным списком